# Unable to port forward in Lubuntu minecraft

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10

SO I have an ASUS RT-N56U router and I am able to port forward using Windows 7 on my other computer, but on that computer it is directly wired to the router.

On the Linux machine I am trying to port forward I am using a wireless adapter, but I don't think it would matter right? My goal is to port forward to the port 25565 TCP and I have set up everything correctly on the ASUS router settings.

When I check to see if the port is open on the Windows machine (which is directly connected to the router via Ethernet cord) it says that the port is OPEN. However when I try to port forward on the Linux machine (that is NOT connected via Ethernet, but with a Rosewill wireless adapter) I get the error that the port is closed for some reason.

My suspicion is that something in Lubuntu is blocking the port like a firewall of some sorts. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I am able to SSH into my Linux machine from My Laptop and Windows 7 machine without a problem so I am very confused.